# how to print fibonacci series in half pyramid pattern and in reverse order?

Tags: python, fibonacci

Here is the explanation of the question. So the question says to print a half pyramid pattern of (n) size. (n) is the user input.now we have to print the Fibonacci series in this half pyramid in riverse order.

The expected output of the program is if n=5

```
377
233 144
89 55 34
21 13 8 5
3 2 1 1 0
```

the code i have writen is as follows:

```
p=[0,1]
def fibo(n):
    a=0
    b=1
    for i in range(n-2):
        x=a+b
        a=b
        b=x
        p.append(x)
    #print(p)
n=int(input())
s=fibo(n)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i>=j:
            print(p[-j],end=" ")
    print(" ")
```

this code doesn't work because of some problems that i haven't able to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to get the right number of Fibonacci terms - I'll let you figure that out - loaded into `p`. It would be better in this case to generate `p` within the method and return it instead of handling it as a global. The meaningless `s` doesn't hold anything here.

The printing part you could handle by `pop`ping elements off the end of the list, provided you didn't want the numbers for some other use:

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print(p.pop(),end=" ")
    print()
```